# What is the difference between smtp server and smtp protocol? Can I also use smtp protocol to send email to non smtp server?

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

What is the difference between smtp server and smtp protocol? Can I also use smtp protocol to send email to non smtp server? Please bear with me, I'm new to these terminologies and trying to setup automated email for some job via Backend java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP server is a computer that is capable of serving content through SMTP protocol.

The protocol itself is the way of communication, specialized for funtionality related to e-mail standards.

For sending automated e-mails, you definitely want to set up your SMTP server, but your target would be an e-mail *address*.

But in order for you to achieve, you need a solid understanding of the underlying theories, so I recommend reading up in the matter at least on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP =  `Simple Mail Transfer Protocol`
SMTP Server = a computer that is running smtp

In order to send emails you need a server.
If you want to send emails from your backend application you may :

- Use 3d party services via api (i.e [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/email-api/))
- Use a public smtp server (i.e [Gmail](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/))
- create an SMTP server (a more complex procedure [IIS6 on windows](https://www.smtp2go.com/setupguide/iis/), [SquirrelMail on linux](https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/))